# Google analytics Embed api not showing charts with my client id

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am using [Google analytics Embed api](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/) for display google analytics report on my website.  I have also been referring to [www.raymondcamden.com/2015/06/10/quick-example-of-the-google-analytics-embed-api](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/06/10/quick-example-of-the-google-analytics-embed-api)

When I use that demo Client ID its work for me, however when I put my Client ID its displaying error in browser console and not working Help for the same thanks in advance
i created credentials in google console developer account
why isn't this code working? with my Client ID for Web application

[image]

[Please see the attached image for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSDo2.png)

```js
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));


gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  // Step 3: Authorize the user.

  var CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE YOUR CLIENT ID';

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  });

  // Step 4: Create the view selector.

  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector'
  });

  // Step 5: Create the timeline chart.

  var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:date',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': '15daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'today',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'LINE',
      container: 'timeline'
    }
  });

  // Step 6: Hook up the components to work together.

  gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
    viewSelector.execute();
  });

  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    var newIds = {
      query: {
        ids: ids
      }
    }
    timeline.set(newIds).execute();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Embed API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Step 1: Create the containing elements. -->

<section id="auth-button"></section>
<section id="view-selector"></section>
<section id="timeline"></section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edited this question but not getting any response

Comment: I solved this issue, i forgot to add origin URI and  Authorized redirect URIs.